# SQL Server Express 2008 with Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to install SQL Server Express 2008 and learn how to deal with a database (learning MVC 4). I have worked with SQL on MySQL/PhpMyAdmin before so that's the only base I have...

I cannot manage the installation of it along with the management tools. After fixing a number of errors, I finally managed to install SQL Server Express 2008 SP3, which came with no Management Studio/Tools. I downloaded SQL Express 2008 Management Studio from the Microsoft website and when I launched it before I installed SQL Express 2008, I got an option for to install the Management Tools. However, if I installed it, I was missing a bunch of stuff (such as the Server Browser) and I could not connect.

So I uninstalled it, and now I have SQL Server Express 2008 without any GUI that I can see other than the Configuration Manager.

However, if I run the Management Studio package I downloaded, now there is no Management Tools box to tick anymore. Does this mean it's already installed? If so, where? I cannot find it in my programs...

I have been trying to get this sorted for days now and I'm really at a loss. How do I install the Management Studio only, for SQL Server 2008?

FYI, I am trying to install this on two machines:

1) Windows 8.1 32bit VM with Visual Studio Express 2013.

2) Windows 7 64bit with Visual Studio 2013.

And can't make it work on either! Though getting it to work on Windows 8.1 is my priority, if you have a solution/tips/tricks for Win 7 that'd be a great start already.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you limited to using 2008. Would you be ok with 2012?

Comment: Unfortunately I have been asked to work with 2008 as, I'm told, is the most widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest uninstalling everything sql and starting over. If you go to the following link below and click the download button you will be presented with two download options. Select the x86 or x64 depending on your processor type. This download includes both the sql engine and the management studio application. Let me know if you have trouble after trying this.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973

Comment: I cannot believe it was so easy. This worked like a charm. Thank you very much!